# sql select query and group by issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Given the following Contract table records

```
Id EmployeeId StartDate    EndDate
1  5601       2011-01-01   2011-09-01
2  5601       2011-09-02   2012-05-01
3  5601       2012-02-01   2012-08-01
4  5602       2011-01-01   2011-09-01
5  5602       2011-07-01   2012-10-01
```

Every Employee could have multiple contract

I'm trying to find invalid contract which `StartDate` is bigger than `EndDate` for each Employee.

For the given result `Id=3` and `Id=5` is invalid .
What i have done is :

```
SELECT a.Id
FROM Contracts a
GROUP BY a.EmpId
HAVING a.StartDate > a.EndDate
```

But I get this error :

```
Column 'Contract.Id' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want records where StartDate is ***not*** bigger then ***previous*** EndDate?
You can do that using [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function - joining the previous and current record.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY StartDate) RN
   FROM Contracts
)
SELECT * FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.RN + 1 = c2.RN AND c1.EmployeeID = c2.EmployeeID
WHERE c1.EndDATE > c2.StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.EmpId
FROM Contracts a
WHERE a.StartDate > a.EndDate
GROUP BY a.Id, a.EmpId
```

Comment: It cause an error : Column 'ContractId' is invalid in the select list  because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by cluse